# Change [faq] link to [help]. Change title of the linked page to "How this site works"

Tags: feature-request, site-faq

This has been bugging me for a long time.  What does the word *faq*<sup>1</sup> mean, anyway?  It hangs in my throat like an errant syllable from the Aflac duck, and I think the term is [*completely undiscoverable* to a new user.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2y8Sx4B2Sk)

Changing the link name to **help**

(or **New users read this** or **Read Me** or pretty much anything except *faaaak*)

...would make the link more discoverable, and perhaps increase the chances that a new user might actually read it before someone tells them to "Read the faq."

Instead of "Frequently Asked Questions" (does anyone actually ask these??), the page should be titled, **"How This Site Works."**

<sup>1. Yes, I do know what the word actually means.</sup>

Comment: Maybe "WTF" would encourage more people to click.

Answer (score 2):

I have had all of these thoughts before, myself. Not just about SE sites, but in general. I eventually came to the conclusion that the use of "faq" to mean "help" or "new users click here" has become a fairly well established convention in our society in spite of the literal meaning of the term "frequently asked questions."

So, I'm not opposed to this request, but I also don't think it'll result in any significant change in the number of new users — or old users — who read that information, or in users' behavior across the network.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [renaming the FAQ tab on the main page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95786/faq-question-tab-is-incorrectly-named), or about [how the FAQ page isn't a FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95224/faq-huhn-what-is-it-good-for) since the real FAQ is the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)?  Whatever, I fully support your war on FAQs.

Comment: 1) Nope.  2) lolwut?