# Make "faq" show the most duplicated questions

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, frequent-tab

The FAQ tab on tags is somewhat misleading in that it actually shows the questions that are most *linked* to, not the ones that are most frequently asked.

We can identify the true "most frequently asked" questions by counting how many times a question is the target of a close-as-exact-duplicate.

My proposal is simple:

- The FAQ tab should show the questions that have been the target of a close-as-exact-duplicate the most times.
- The existing FAQ tab could be kept, and renamed to "most linked" to more accurately reflect its function.

Comment: related: [Faq question tab is incorrectly named](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95786/faq-question-tab-is-incorrectly-named)