# Tweak the Frequent tab's tooltip

Tags: feature-request, tooltips, frequent-tab

Currently the [<del>FAQ</del> Frequent tab](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq)'s tooltip reads "questions with the most links". More accurate would be "questions linked to the most" (or "linked to most often"); "questions with the most links" sounds almost like it's a list of questions with lots of links in the question body (and why would I care about that?).

I know [the actual label for that tab got an overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95786/faq-question-tab-is-incorrectly-named) and I think tweaking the tooltip would further help one of the most confusing tab names (after that dastardly unanswered tab which means "not answered enough").

Answer (score 3):

"Most frequently referenced questions"

Comment: Though I understand where you're going with this could you expand upon your answer a bit please? It's a little disconcerting...

Comment: Sure. The "frequent" tag has questions that are most frequently referenced, so a good tooltip would be "most frequently referenced questions".

Answer (score 1):

How about "**Questions with the most inbound links**"?

Comment: Are those links inbound only from that site, or from anywhere on the stackexchange network, or what?